# c# if statement, switch statement

Tags: c#

Let's make it easier. In this case return at the end have squigglies. What should I type in the return at the end to receive VK_F2 as a return value from the method?

```
internal uint AssignStartShortcut()
    {
        switch (currentStartValue)
        {
            case "F2":
                return VK_F2;
        }
        return;// how this should look?
    }
```

If I don't use return after swith then I have message: not all code paths return value.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting guys, this is my first question in stackOverflow

Comment: And, what exactly is your question?

Comment: You **CAN** fix your formatting

Comment: What is the error message associated with the squiggly lines?

Comment: Adding to TheGeneral's comment. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56438650/edit) your post to fix the formatting. Also you always see a live preview of how your question will look at the bottom of the edit page. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is some documentation about the Stack Overflow flavored markdown

Comment: And please go through [ask]

Answer (score 5):

Your error most likely is:

[Compiler Error CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165)

> Use of unassigned local variable 'name'
>
> The C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. If
> the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been
> initialized, it generates compiler error CS0165. For more information,
> see Fields. Note that this error is generated when the compiler
> encounters a construct that might result in the use of an unassigned
> variable, even if your particular code does not. This avoids the
> necessity of overly-complex rules for definite assignment.

Easy fix, initialize it:

```
internal uint AssignStopShortcut()
{
   uint stopNumber = 0;
   switch (currentStartValue)
   ...
```

Or make sure the static analyser knows that it can't fall through (i.e it is always initialized)

```
uint stopNumber;

switch (currentStartValue)
{
   case "F3":
      stopNumber = VK_F3;

      return stopNumber; //squigly lines below
   default:
      // no other options
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Bazzinga!");
}
```

Or even better, just return the *constant*, don't use the local variable.

```
internal uint AssignStopShortcut()
{
   switch (currentStartValue)
   {
      case "F3":
         return VK_F3; //squigly lines below
      default:
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Bazzinga!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx for help General. I tried all 3 solutions. First one is crashing the app. 2nd and 3rd calling Bazzinga! :) Thanks again but i think it is me not explaining well enough of what i am trying to get back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the TheGeneral's solution, your problem is that you need to initialise the variable.

```
internal uint AssignStartShortcut()
{
    uint startNumber = 0; //initialise variable
    if (currentStartValue == "F2")
    {
        startNumber = VK_F2;
    }
    return startNumber; //value of 0 is returned if the IF statement conditon is not met.
}
```

From your comment to TheGenral's proposed solution as I cannot yet make comments, is that since the initialised variable is set to Zero in this case and you are only doing a check  for a particular value and if that condition is not met then "startNumber" won't be updated with "VK_F2" or "VK_F3" values. Therefore, that's why the Switch statement default case is met as the "currentStartValue" had not met any of the cases.

For example if you wanted to check for all cases, it should look something like this:

```
    internal uint AssignStopShortcut()
    {
        uint stopNumber = 0; //initialise this variable is a must if it's to be declared in this method.
        switch (currentStartValue)
        {
            case "F1": break;
            case "F2": break;
            case "F3":
                stopNumber = VK_F3;
                break;
            case "F4": break;
            case "F5": break;
            case "F6": break;
            case "F7": break;
            case "F8": break;
            default:
                // no other options
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Bazzinga!");
        }
        return stopNumber;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so to make sure the condition is passed i could simply print current start value before the method will run. Then i will now what is passed. Is what i am saying correct?

Comment: Yes, you should check what is passed into "currentStartValue" to see if "F2" is passed through, if so then the IF statement should be met.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you guys for your help. Problem solved and it wasn't in if or switch statement. Turns out data that should be passed simply wasn't. My bad. Thanks again.